# Write a dataset to HDF5 using a user defined Class (C++)

Tags: c++, hdf5

My data set is an N x N matrix and it represents a scalar field.

The matrix representation is done by defining my own scalar field class. This way, I can avoid double pointers and I can write my data in a contiguous chunk of memory. Hence, `FIELD(i,j)` translates to `FIELD[i + N*j]`.

Now, I wrote the following code to write some data to HDF5 (a matrix full of twos).

```
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#include "Mesh2D.h"

using namespace H5;

int main()
{

  int Nx = 10;
  int Ny = 10;
  
  Mesh2D HFIELD{Nx,Ny,0};
  HFIELD.meshfill(2);
  HFIELD.print();

  //Create HDF5 file//
  const H5std_string FILE_NAME("EXAMPLE_DSET.h5");
  H5File file(FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);

  //Create the data space for the data set//
  hsize_t dims[2];
  const int RANK = 2;
  dims[0] = Nx;
  dims[1] = Ny;
  DataSpace dataspace(RANK,dims);

  //Create the dataset//
  const H5std_string DATASET_NAME("dset");
  DataSet dataset = file.createDataSet(DATASET_NAME, PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE, dataspace);

  //Write the data to the dataset using default memory space, file space and transfer properties//
  dataset.write(HFIELD, PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
  
  return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘H5::DataSet::write(Mesh2D&, const H5::PredType&)’
   34 |   dataset.write(HFIELD, PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Does variable `HFIELD` has a method that you can call which returns the underlying memory address where the values (to be written into the dataset) are stored? Otherwise, and looking at your code, I'm not sure how method `write` can use `HFIELD` just like that.

Comment: No, I have not such a method but lets say that I implement a method that returns the memory address of the chunk of memory. Then what?

Comment: Then pass this memory address to method `write` (instead of just bluntly `HFIELD`).

Comment: I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: It works, I managed to write it and read it. I guess I should have read the documentation of `write`. Maybe I could have figured this out my own. But thanks again.